# Cant run nextjs app with internationalization i18n in docker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, next.js, internationalization

The app is written with typescript.
The build is succeed, but when I launch the program in localhost:3000 I get this error

```
TypeError: The URL is not configured with i18n
    at URL.get locale [as locale] (/app/.next/server/pages/_middleware.js:1:46515)
```

in my dockerfile I copied all the needed files

```
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
COPY next.config.js /app/next.config.js
COPY .next /app/.next 
COPY public /app/public
```

the `next.config.js` contains:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "fr"],

    defaultLocale: "en",

  },
};
```

in `next.config.js` I try to add the `rewrites` function but still get the same error.

```
    async rewrites() {
      return [
        {
          source: "/",
          destination: "/",
          locale: false, // Use `locale: false` so that the prefix matches the desired locale correctly
        },
        {
          source: "/fr/test",
          destination: "/fr/test",
          locale: false, // Use `locale: false` so that the prefix matches the desired locale correctly
        },
      ];
    },
```

the _middleware.ts contains:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const shouldHandleLocale =
    !PUBLIC_FILE.test(request.nextUrl.pathname) &&
    !request.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/api/") &&
    request.nextUrl.locale === "default";

  return shouldHandleLocale
    ? NextResponse.redirect(`/en${request.nextUrl.href}`)
    : undefined;
}
```

it seems that the middleware not working.
any helpful hint or ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this work outside of docker? if it does I bet you haven't copied your next.config into your app folder in the dockerfile.  I just had the same problem.

Comment: @DavidB thanks, Yes it was there! my issue was copy the `next.config` into the build part too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to copy the `next.config` in all the docker images `deps`, `builder`, `runner`
this the docker file is the sample of `nextjs`

```
FROM node:16-alpine as deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run build && npm install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
RUN addgroup group && adduser -system -group user
USER user
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=user:group /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

the. `next.config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
  swcMinify: false,
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: Glad my comment helped you figure this one out, I think including the relevant code of the dockerfile showing the copying of the `next.config.js` will help the answer here, also some additional context, for example the `next.config.js` contains the `I8n` configuration so is required in the application folder for routing.

Comment: Thanks @DavidB, I just update my answer you can add any useful information.